# Trying to adapt Node.js Twitter script to post two images at a time instead of one?

Tags: node.js, twitter

Trying to modify this [script](https://gist.github.com/fourtonfish/b307d5d94d6f38efbf0a1be8e2ebd19b) to Tweet two random images instead together instead of just one. Know there has to be a simple solution, but I am new to javascript and coding in general, and I guess I am missing something. Tried repeating a couple of lines:

```
  /* Then pick random images. */

  const imagePath = path.join( __dirname, '/images/' + randomFromArray( images ) ),
        b64content = fs.readFileSync( imagePath, { encoding: 'base64' } );
        
  const imagePath2 = path.join( __dirname, '/images/' + randomFromArray2( images ) ),
        b64content2 = fs.readFileSync( imagePath2, { encoding: 'base64' } );

  /* Upload the image to Twitter. */
  
  T.post( 'media/upload', { media_data: b64content, b64content2 }, function ( err, data, response ) {
    if ( err ){
      console.log( 'error:', err );
    }
    else{

 /* And finally, post a tweet with the image. */

      T.post( 'statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array( data.media_id_string )
      },
        function( err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log( 'error:', err );
          }
          else{
            console.log( 'posted images!' );
          }
        }
      );
    }
  } );
```

...But I am unsure how the `media_data` is being generated and then how this connects to the `media_ids: new Array( data.media_id_string )` line for posting. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated - many thanks in advance!

Comment: The `media/upload` API function does not support more than one media object at a time, so you cannot simply add in another base64 value there. You would need to post the two images individually, grab the `media_id_string` from each one, and then add them both to `media_ids`

Comment: @AndyPiper Thank you - that totally makes sense. I will rework this accordingly with additional `T.Post` lines